# errorcode 104 while hitting the execution API of Zapi

Tags: jira-rest-api, python-jira, jira-zephyr

While trying to create a new execution of a cycle in zephyr I am getting an error code of 104. I have tried it through postman as well of which i am pasting a screenshot as well. please any type of guidance would be great[image]
Below is the body that i am sending
`{"projectId": 10000, "issueId": 10000, "versionId": -1}`

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue - a few things to check:

1. Make sure that your JWT token request is using the user's account ID instead of email. This was recently changed due to GDPR. Here is an [example](https://github.com/zephyrdeveloper/zapi_csharp/blob/master/ZapiCSharp/ZapiCSharp.cs#L70-L76).
2. Check the "Disable Jira Permission on Zephyr Rest API" checkbox in Jira's administration section for Zephyr (Admin -> Apps -> Zephyr -> General Configuration)